# Erro "Cannot read properties of undefined belongsToMany" sequelize / nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize-js

estou desenvolvendo um projeto usando nodejs, sequelize e typescript mas estou com as mensagens abaixo ao configurar o relacionamento N:N entre as tabelas `sales` e `products`

```
Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'belongsToMany')
```

e

```
Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'belongsToMany')
```

Tenho 4 tabelas `users`, `products`, `sales` e `salesProducts` e o relacionamento entre as tabelas `sales` e `products` com a tabela `salesProducts` é **N:N**

quando faço a associação dentro da tabela salesProducts o erro a seguir é exibido **"error": "products is not associated to sales!"**

e quando faço a associação dentro das tabelas sales e products o erro **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'belongsToMany')** é exibido

abaixo vou deixar as configurações de arquivos

dentro do arquivo **database/config/database.ts**

```
import "dotenv/config";

const config = {
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectOptions: {
    timezone: "Z",
  },
  logging: false,
};

module.exports = config;
```

dentro do arquivo **database/models/index.model.ts**

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import * as config from '../config/database';

export default new Sequelize(config);
```

dentro do arquivo **database/models/products.model.ts**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Sales from './sales.model';
import SalesProducts from './salesproducts.model';

class Products extends Model {
  declare id: number;
  declare name: string;
  declare type: string;
  declare price: number;
  declare quantity: number;
  declare url_image: string;
}

Products.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  type: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  quantity: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  url_image: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'products',
  timestamps: false,
});

Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
  as: 'sales',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'productId',
  otherKey: 'saleId',
});

export default Products;
```

dentro do arquivo **database/models/sales.model.ts**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Users from './users.model';
import Products from './products.model';
import SalesProducts from './salesproducts.model';

class Sales extends Model {
  declare id: number;
  declare userId: string;
  declare sellerId: string;
  declare totalPrice: number;
  declare saleDate: Date;
  declare statusSale: string;
}

Sales.init({
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  userId: DataTypes.STRING,
  sellerId: DataTypes.STRING,
  totalPrice: { type: DataTypes.DECIMAL, allowNull: false },
  saleDate: { type: DataTypes.DATE, defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW },
  statusSale: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'sales',
  timestamps: false,
});

// relacionamento entre tabelas users e sales
Users.hasMany(Products, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  as: 'saleId'
})

Sales.belongsTo(Users, {
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  as: 'user_id'
})

// relacionamento entre tabelas sales e products
Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
  as: 'products',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'saleId',
  otherKey: 'productId',
});

export default Sales;
```

dentro do arquivo **database/models/salesProducts.ts**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Products from './products.model';
import Sales from './sales.model';

class SalesProducts extends Model {
  declare saleId: number;
  declare productId: number;
  declare quantity: number;
  static associate: (models: any) => void;
}

SalesProducts.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  saleId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: { model: 'sales', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    field: 'sale_id',
  },
  productId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: { model: 'products', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    field: 'product_id',
  },
  quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'salesProducts',
  timestamps: false,
});

// Caso a associação ocorra aqui o erro a seguir aparece: "error": "products is not associated to sales!"

// Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
//   as: 'sale',
//   through: SalesProducts,
//   foreignKey: 'productId',
//   otherKey: 'saleId',
// });

// Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
//   as: 'products',
//   through: SalesProducts,
//   foreignKey: 'saleId',
//   otherKey: 'productId',
// });

export default SalesProducts;
```

e a chamada para a query ocorre aqui em **services/sales.ts**

```
import Sales from '../database/models/sales.model';
import Users from '../database/models/users.model';
import Products from '../database/models/products.model';

class SaleService {
  private Sales = Sales;
  private Users = Users;
  private Products = Products;

  public async getSales() {
    const sales =  await this.Sales.findAll(
      {
        include: [
          { model: this.Users, as: 'user_id', attributes: { exclude: ['password'] } },
          { model: this.Products, as: 'product', through: { attributes: [] } }, //caso essa linha seja ocultada consigo realizar a consulta, visualizando os dados da compra e dados de usuário
        ]
      }
    );
    return sales;
  }
export { SaleService }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Os erros que você está recebendo parecem indicar que as classes Sequelize Sales e Products não estão sendo exportadas corretamente dos seus respectivos arquivos e, portanto, suas funções associativas belongsToMany não podem ser encontradas.

Você pode corrigir isso exportando essas classes corretamente. Tente exportar suas classes Sales e Products como default, em vez de exportá-las como objetos nomeados:

typescript
Copy code

```
// products.model.ts
export default Products;

// sales.model.ts
export default Sales;
```

Além disso, você deve exportar a classe SalesProducts também, para que possa ser referenciada por outras classes:

typescript
Copy code

```
// salesproducts.model.ts
export default SalesProducts;
```

Com essas correções, você deve ser capaz de usar as funções associativas belongsToMany corretamente.